# Span inside button takes whole height

Tags: css

I have a button with a span icon inside it. I want the icon to be a bit more vertical centered from the text inside the button, but the span is taking the whole height of the button. This way the text also moves when I put margin-top with the text.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26184/

I've put the `background-color:red;` to show my problem.

I don't think that giving it a standard hight is a clean fix for it.

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
span.glyphicon-envelope {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button>
  Send
  <span class="glyphicon-envelope"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `line-height: 50px;`. Also your jsfiddle points to something else it seems?

```
span.glyphicon-envelope {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Ups, you are right, forgot to click update. Thanks for your answer, will click accept in 2 minutes

Comment: Btw, would you perhaps know why, when I add margin-top to the icon, it also moves the text inside the button?

Comment: @C.Ronaldo you can put relative on the icon and push the pixels like that (also as Paul Knight mention). I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the line-height and remove padding in span.glyphicon-envelope

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

span.glyphicon-envelope {
    padding-left: 1px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button>
  Send
  <span class="glyphicon-envelope"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `button` display to table-cell and add `vertical-align: middle` to span `glyphicon-envelope`

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
span.glyphicon-envelope {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See an example: https://jsfiddle.net/pdz696pv/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do:

```
span.glyphicon-envelope {
position: relative;
top: 2px;
}
```

Changing the value of the top property will move it up and down (you could use bottom as well obviously).

This is a simple solution if you don't wish to change any of the other properties of the envelope.